# using svyglm from a glm perspective

Tags: r

I have been using glm to run logistic regressions. However, I need to use svyglm because my weights are probability weights. However, I really don't understand the documentation for svyglm.

As an example, I am using this data setup, which should give a pweight that suggests this is a perfectly representative sample:

```
data("mtcars")    
mtcars$pweight <- ifelse(mtcars$cyl == 4, (11/32), ifelse(mtcars$cyl == 6, (7/32), (14/32)))
mtcars$goodcar <- rbinom(n=32, size=1, prob=0.3)
```

If I use the unweighted glm command for the regression, I get the following result:

```
mylogit <- glm(goodcar ~ mpg + disp + hp,  data = mtcars, family = "binomial", weights = pweight)
summary(mylogit)

call:
glm(formula = goodcar ~ mpg + disp + hp, family = "binomial", 
    data = mtcars)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.6633  -0.7404  -0.4651   0.8658   1.9408  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept) -0.279806   4.800398  -0.058   0.9535  
mpg          0.016486   0.145431   0.113   0.9097  
disp         0.020622   0.009257   2.228   0.0259 *
hp          -0.041091   0.021168  -1.941   0.0522 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 39.75  on 31  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 31.27  on 28  degrees of freedom
AIC: 39.27

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

Based on the above, I tried to set it up like this:

```
design <- svydesign(
  id = ~0 , #no clusters
  data = mtcars ,
  weights = ~pweight 
)

mysvyglm <- svyglm(goodcar ~ mpg + disp + hp,  data = mtcars, design, family = "binomial")
summary(mysvyglm)
    
Call:
svyglm(formula = goodcar ~ mpg + disp + hp, design = design, 
    family = "binomial", data = mtcars)

Survey design:
svydesign(id = ~0, data = mtcars, weights = ~pweight)

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  0.756867   4.655046   0.163   0.8720  
mpg         -0.019180   0.150333  -0.128   0.8994  
disp         0.017538   0.008974   1.954   0.0607 .
hp          -0.037779   0.017197  -2.197   0.0365 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 0.8997231)

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

Am I wrong to think that the glm and the svyglm should be the same in this case, as the pweights show the sample is representative? I feel like I'm missing something and getting this setup wrong.

Comment: Is this a typo? Don't you mean `summary(mysvyglm)`? `svydesign svydesign` is one of the functions provided by the `survey` package.

Comment: ugh - such a dumb mistake. Yes, that was a typo; I still don't think I'm getting this right and rewrote the question a bit (without the typo) to reflect that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mtcars dataset is small: it has only 32 observations. Let's generate a larger dataset. The simulation is simple and doesn't take the inverse weight sampling into account.

And I've added a third model, `geepack::geeglm`, that can fit a GLM with inverse probability weighting.

With the larger dataset, all three models have the same estimates for the coefficients and their standard errors.

Part 1. Generate data

```r
library("survey")
library("geepack")
library("tidyverse")

set.seed(1234)

inv_logit <- function(x) {
  plogis(x)
}

n <- 100

# Gnerate dataset
mydata <-
  tibble(
    id = seq(n),
    x1 = rnorm(n),
    x2 = rnorm(n),
    x3 = rnorm(n),
    y = rbinom(n,
      size = 1,
      prob = inv_logit(0.1 * x1 + 0.2 * x2 + 0.3 * x3) + rnorm(n, sd = 0.1)
    ),
    pweight = runif(n)
  ) %>%
  # geeglm requires the data is ordered by time (or observation) within each cluster
  arrange(id)
```

Part 2. Fit models

```r
fit.glm <- glm(
  y ~ x1 + x2 + x3,
  weights = pweight,
  family = "binomial",
  data = mydata
)
#> Warning in eval(family$initialize): non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
tidy(fit.glm)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)   -0.319     0.340    -0.938  0.348 
#> 2 x1             0.638     0.362     1.77   0.0776
#> 3 x2             0.591     0.372     1.59   0.112 
#> 4 x3             0.972     0.446     2.18   0.0291

design <- svydesign(
  id = ~1,
  weights = ~pweight,
  data = mydata
)

fit.svyglm <- svyglm(
  y ~ x1 + x2 + x3,
  design = design,
  family = "binomial",
  data = mydata
)
#> Warning in eval(family$initialize): non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
tidy(fit.svyglm)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)   -0.319     0.269     -1.18 0.239  
#> 2 x1             0.638     0.293      2.18 0.0317 
#> 3 x2             0.591     0.297      1.99 0.0497 
#> 4 x3             0.972     0.329      2.95 0.00397

fit.geeglm <- geeglm(
  y ~ x1 + x2 + x3,
  id = mydata$id,
  weights = pweight,
  family = "binomial",
  corstr = "independence",
  data = mydata
)
#> Warning in eval(family$initialize): non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
tidy(fit.geeglm)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)   -0.319     0.268      1.42 0.234  
#> 2 x1             0.638     0.291      4.80 0.0284 
#> 3 x2             0.591     0.296      3.99 0.0457 
#> 4 x3             0.972     0.328      8.80 0.00301
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>